# Eliminating the Do..Until loop with very slow completion

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6

I need a vital help here.
 I have a VB6 app that has existed for more than 7 years to which i have a few clients using it for their accounting solutions. Now my problem is a particular client have grown so big with a 15GB database size, a ledger database table of more than 4 million rows, customer size of more than 100,000, ETC.

I have a code in that app, where customers are debited for a flat rate after checking some parameters, for a client with a small or average database, it works just fine, but for this particular client, this code sometimes does not even complete in 6 hours and its becoming a serious headache and i need help !

The codes looks like this .......

```
Select * from table Customers order by account number
do until rst.eof

   select * from table purchase where account number = rst!account number
   if found 
   A1 = "YES"
   else
   A1 = "NO"

   A2 = new charges on form / 100
   A3 = rst!Balance + A2

   select count(*) from table receipts where account number = rst!account number and month = currentmonth and year = current year
   if count > 10 then
   goto VBSTOP
   else
   CONTINUE

   select * from table seller where account number = rst!account number
   if found 
   A4 = "YES"
   else
   A4 = "NO"

insert into table ledger (Account number, Account name, A1, A3, A4, Charges)
insert into table Charges (Account number, Account name, Charges)
insert into table Receipts (Account number, Account name, Charges, Receipt Number)
update table purchase (update purchaseno = purchaseno + 1 where account number = rst!account number

rst.MoveNext
loop
```

...........................................................................................................

This code takes more than 6 hours to complete for the client with a very large database and i am sincerely looking for help in solving my DO....UNTIL loop headache. Is there a way to optimize this code and eliminate the do until statement or make it run a very very lot faster ?

I would appreciate every help from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: Can you explain what your code want to do, and how you're doing it?

Comment: Part of your problem is that you're still using VB6..... But anyways, you will receive better responses from [codereview.se] as you have _working_ code in need of optimization. This site is for broken code.

Comment: @user202729, the above code is an example of what i want to achieve, i would have attached a small program of real code if there was a way to attach here. But the code above is a simplified example of what i want to achieve and i just need a way to make that code work super fast. Maybe without using the DO...UNTIL statement and still achieve same aim. Thanksssss.

Comment: Well. You're in need of some serious database and query optimization. Way beyond the scope of an answer here, to 'do it right' requires a full understanding of the database schema and business process flow. Basic idea is usually to reduce the number of records accessed on the server (I'm simplifying a lot here), so based on your pseudo process above, and making a number of assumptions (not discussed here), I'd start with the query to the receipts table for the current time period, then do the references to the purchase, customer and seller tables for the related records. 1/2

Comment: That would presumably avoid access the customers, accounts, etc, that didn't have any activity in the current time period. Also proper primary keys and indices are needed for efficiency. Alternatively, or in addition, rather than running separate select, insert and update queries, joined queries and sub-queries can improve performance. SQL Server Performance Monitor can tell you where your queries are using a lot of cpu and io, concentrating on those can reap quick benefits. Stored procedures can also provide performance improvements. 2/2   Good Luck.

Comment: If your db is sql server try move this logic to stored procedure

Comment: The first thing to do is to insert timing code into the existing program and determine which portion(s) take the longest. Until you do that you are shooting blind.

Comment: How are you accessing the data, OLE DB, ADO, ...? Some more information about your cursor would be helpful. Different cursor types are faster to retrieve when you don't need to see updates made by other users.

Comment: Hey, @TobyyDamian. The suspense is killing me. Did you have any success?

Comment: @Troy Turley, no success yet. Got the best help from M.Doerner but i am still stuck cos no one has seem to be able to completely help me solve the issue i have had for weeks now

Answer (score 4):

Several suggestions:

- Instead of Select *, select only the columns you need. This will reduce the size of the recordset.
- Make sure all of the columns used in your where clauses are indexed
  (account, month, year).
- Convert your 3 inserts and the update into a single stored procedure
  call.
- In the cases where you're checking for the existence of a record try
  "Select TOP 1" then the column name of the Primary Key.
- Run it in debug to see which step takes the longest.

I don't have code for you. I would have just commented, but I haven't earned that privilege.